# maven upload file per scp

Tags: java, maven-2, maven, wagon, maven-wagon-plugin

whats the preferred way to upload an artifact via scp to a predefined destination?
i tried using the wagon:upload mojo, but it wont execute atomatically when i defined a "executions" section in my pom like that:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>release</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>upload</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <fromDir>target/checkout/target</fromDir>
        <includes>*.jar</includes>
        <url>scpexe://host/dir</url>
        <toDir />
        <serverId>my id</serverId>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

i added the necessary extension wagon-ssh and wagon-ssh-external and it all works fine when i execute wagon:upload but it wont upload the artifact automatically in the release phase.

Is this even the right way to upload artifacts to a website, or should the deploy plugin take care of that?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because no `release` phase exists (see [Maven Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference))

You probably want phase `deploy`. And yes, wagon is usually used by the maven deploy plugin (automatically when you execute `mvn deploy`).